# excludeTags in facets does not exclude a term

Tags: solr, faceted-search, exclude-constraint

My document collection has an attribute cfname2. Using JSON API I can query `*:*` and facet on this attribute and exclude `00` term:

```
GET http://localhost:5555/solr/db/query HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json

{ 
    "query" : "*:*",
    "limit": 0,
    "facet": {
        "t" : {
            "type":  "terms",
            "field": "cfname2",
            "limit": 10,
            "sort":  "index",
            "domain": {"excludeTags": "00"}
        }
    }
}
```

independent whether I use `excludeTags` or not, `00` is in the answer:

```
 "response": {
    "numFound": 20560849,
    "start": 0,
    "numFoundExact": true,
    "docs": []
  },
  "facets": {
    "count": 20560849,
    "t": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "val": "0",
          "count": 831411
        },
        {
          "val": "00",
          "count": 861685
        },
        {
          "val": "01",
          "count": 198584
        },
```

I wonder why this does not work. How can I exclude terms matching regex `[0-9][0-9]` using the above JSON?

Comment: `excludeTags` works to exclude _filters_ that have been tagged with a particular tag, not for removing terms. Filters work on sets of documents, and facets uses that set of documents to generate the facets. Do you want to exclude a set of _terms_ from a facet, or a set of _documents_ that contain that term (and in effect the term and associated terms in those documents)?

Comment: Great explanation. Now I understand where my confusion comes. Indeed `excludeTags` excludes filters, not terms (it starts all making sense why people all over the net talk about `{!tag=xxx}` to define those filters and `{!ex=xxx}` to exclude them). I wanted to exclude terms, as for the documents I am looking for all of them

Comment: How dynamic is the list of terms you want to exclude? If it's static, you can implement it as a custom field with a stop filter containing those terms. That will be the most efficient implementation.